# Fixing iPhone memory leaks, getting started

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, memory-leaks

I am an experienced C/C++ programmer, and familiar with memory management issues.  I've also shipped a couple small iPhone apps in the past.  I am attempting to check my latest app for memory leaks, and I can't make any headway, because there are so many of them.  Just starting the app and viewing the first screen shows over 12,000 leaks.

I know I've probably overlooked various things, but I was reasonably cautious in writing the code.  I made attempts to release everything I alloc'ed in my dealloc method.  It is like my app delegate never gets released, because I can see a couple things that are only alloc'ed once, in the app delegate's init method.  They are never modified, and are released in the dealloc method.

This app is built around a tab controller, with around 15 views mainly set up using Interface Builder.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your app delegate isn't likely to get released during the lifetime of your app, unless you do it explicitly. You typically want it to stick around until the app quits, which doesn't need to call dealloc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instruments of apple is pretty advanced.. it can show you the exact method that originally created the memory leak, I suggest taking a look at those methods and carefully reading your code ,there usually is this line of code in there and you thought OMG how could I be that stupid.

If that doesn't help, try to "Analyze" with xcode, its pretty good at finding errors and leaks in your code and saved my *** a couple of times.

Comment: Yes, I've looked at the stack traces and lines of code.  In this case, I was looking at objects created in the app delegate's init method.  They are properties too, if that matters.  I've tried using both the property . notation: `self.thing = [[[Thing alloc] init];` autorelease]; as well as traditional direct means: `thing = [[Thing alloc] init];`

Comment: if you use self.thing = you need to autorelease as the object will be retained again, if you do instance var = directly you shouldn't autorelease. I hope you didn't forget to implement the dealloc method to release your instance variables?

Comment: OK, I am a moron.  I had "Allocations" highlighted in Instruments, not "Leaks".  The actual number of leaks is reasonable.

Comment: "The actual number of leaks is reasonable"?  There should be NO leaks! :)